# JavaScript window.open() and broken URLs

Tags: javascript

Found a broken link on the company site today, after some digging, here's what I found: a simple JS function to open an FAQ.aspx page within a master HTML page's site navigation.

```
function openFAQ() {
        window.open(location.protocol + "help/FAQ.aspx", "null", "width=750, height=800, resizable=1, scrollbars=1, location=0, directories=0, status=no, menubar=no, toolbar=no");
}
```

The site is dynamically pieced together. From the main page (primary web app)

`http://example.com/index.aspx`

the link to the FAQ works -- With the correct URL being

`http://example.com/help/FAQ.aspx`

If I navigate to

`http://example.com/userpages/settings.aspx`

the menu is still available, but when FAQ is clicked, it generates the following URL:

`http://example.com/userpages/help/FAQ.aspx`.

Putting `"~/help/FAQ.aspx"` doesn't work as it does for src or href. Not sure how to get this working. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.open("/help/FAQ.aspx"....)` should do the trick

Comment: haha, wow, thank you. Just curious, is `/` javascript's way of denoting the root? And is `~/` more a html/terminal thing?

Comment: Good question. Its a root-relative url and I believe it's actually in the HTML specification and not JavaScript, although I didn't look. For example, you could do `<a href="/home/FAQ.aspx">Help Link</a>` in HTML and it would work the same way.

`~` is ASP.Net server-side thing and denotes folder on the file system where the application is running.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should work,

```
 function openFAQ() {
            window.open(window.location.hostname+ "/help/FAQ.aspx", "null", "width=750, height=800, resizable=1, scrollbars=1, location=0, directories=0, status=no, menubar=no, toolbar=no");
    }

location.protocol  provides the protocol used, e.g., http:, https: etc
location.hostname provides the hostname, e.g., www.mysite.com
```